# python selenium script doesn't run in chrome headless mode

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I'm currently doing some web scraping with selenium and my script runs fine on chrome v60.0.3112.90 on windows 10 but I'm having an error when I run it in headless mode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T460\Desktop\reboot.py", line 13, in <module>
    UsernameField = browser.find_element_by_id('input_URN')
  File "C:\Users\T460\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 330, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\T460\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\T460\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\T460\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"input_URN"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=60.0.3112.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Comment: The error says it all. Look at line 13. `browser.find_element_by_id('input_URN')` is throwing `NoSuchElementException`. Possibly incorrect locator or you have to wait for the element.

Comment: i tried to wait for the element but i'm having the same error. the problem is that the script is running flawlessly in non-headless mode i'm on only having this error when i use the --headless flag.

Comment: Consider updating the relevant HTML or the `url` if it is a public one for further analysis.